# Sequelize raw query: Valid SQL query returns nothing

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

My sequelize query always returns 0 results,
but when I copy/paste the exact same query into psql it works fine, returning the correct rows exactly as expected

```
  return sequelize.query(
"SELECT * FROM orders" +
" INNER JOIN sizes ON orders.sizeid = sizes.sizeid" +
" INNER JOIN types ON sizes.typeid = types.typeid" +
" INNER JOIN items ON types.itemid = items.itemid" +
" WHERE orders.fbid = :fbid AND pickuptime >= :today" +
" ORDER BY orders.pickuptime ASC",
{ replacements: {fbid, today}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
```

);

fbid is an integer & today is a string of shape 'yyyy-mm-dd'

If I drop the 'today' condition, I get rows returned

Is sequelize escaping my date string?

Comment: Did you try executing the generated `select` directly into the database (e.g. through command line)? I think that you are missing single-quote chars around `:today`.

Comment: Incidentally, if you know the value of `today`, why don't you deploy it directly as part of the string instead of using the binding mechanism?

Comment: unfortunately the value of :today isn't constant, and surrounding it with single quotes throws an error in sequelize's parsing.

Comment: I can execute the generated query through CLI and get the desired response, but when sequelize executes it something else goes wrong

Comment: Well, if after removing the `today` part things work OK, the only thing I can think of is the way you pass it towards the DB (syntax). If you run the same `SELECT` statement directly into the DB, you WILL need to wrap the date value in single-quotes. I don't know **sequelize** and hence cannot help you beyond this point. Sorry.

Comment: Also, what I meant by deploying the actual value of the date instead of using binding, the idea is: If at the time of the invocation the value of `today` is known, just make it part of the string instead of using binding. In any case, you are **building** the command (string), aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

If you defined named parameter like it `fbid=:fbid` in the SQL script, 
you should pass an object `{fbid: 'fbid_value'}`,

or if you defined unnamed parameters `fbid=?`, you should pass an array `['fbid_value']`.

Here's docs http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#querysql-options-promise

Try to pass an object to replacement:

```
return sequelize.query(
"SELECT * FROM orders" +
" INNER JOIN sizes ON orders.sizeid = sizes.sizeid" +
" INNER JOIN types ON sizes.typeid = types.typeid" +
" INNER JOIN items ON types.itemid = items.itemid" +
" WHERE orders.fbid = :fbid AND pickuptime >= :today" +
" ORDER BY orders.pickuptime ASC",
{ replacements: {fbid: 'fbid_value', today: 'today_value'}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
);
```